# SOQL List of Leads

Tags: apex, soql

I have created a simple vf page with 1 single select picklist(Application) and 1 multiselect picklist(Application Status) ; code below.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="registration-no">Application: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedApplication}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Application_1_Lead_Status__c" itemLabel="Application 1"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Application_2_Lead_Status__c" itemLabel="Application 2"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Application_3_Lead_Status__c" itemLabel="Application 3"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="registration-no">Application Status: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <apex:selectList value="{!ApplicationStatus}" multiselect="true" size="3">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="New" itemLabel="New"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Working" itemLabel="Working"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Switch off / Phone Ringing" itemLabel="Switch off / Phone Ringing"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Not Eligible" itemLabel="Not Eligible"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in its class i want to write a SOQL which will give list of leads where selectedApplication(output of first picklist) IN ApplicationStatus(Multiselect picklist)

eg if i select "Application 1" in first picklist and "New;Working" these 2 values in 2nd picklist then that query should work like:-

```
Select id from Lead where Application_1_Lead_Status__c = "New" 
    OR Application_1_Lead_Status__c = "Working" ;
```

Also all 3 fields (Application_1_Lead_Status__c,Application_2_Lead_Status__c,Application_3_Lead_Status__c) are single select picklists.

I was hoping ...something like this would work :

```
Select id from Lead where selectedApplication In ApplicationStatus
```

but ApplicationStatus will have value something like New;Working which will not work with In clause of SOQL.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/194040/edit) your question and add what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added an example of what i have tried

Comment: why just not split the values(so that can be used with IN) and use dynamic query to make your own string ?

Comment: Yeah that could work...Let me try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So dynamic query is way to go.

Create a method like this may be ?

```
public static List<Lead> query(String field, String values){
    List<String> statuses = values.split(';');
    return Database.query('SELECT Id, FROM Lead WHERE '+field+' IN:statuses');

}
```

And you can call the same from your button action or wherever you want from

```
List<Lead> leads = query(selectedApplication, ApplicationStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...but query is not returning proper results. In my console i ran a query :- SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Application_1_Lead_Status__c IN ('New','Working')     which returned me 20 records but query generated from method :- SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Application_1_Lead_Status__c IN:statuses  is returning 0 records.  i used debug log to see value of statuses variable and it was : [New, Working]

Comment: I tried doing this my dev seems to be working, make sure right variables are passed along

Comment: Yes i am using all variable correctly....thats why the output of above method is coming as : SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Application_1_Lead_Status__c IN:statuses    which is correct but i also printed values of "statuses"  & they were shown like [New, Working] which i think is wrong

Comment: I passed a list of string:-  String[] statuses22 = new String[]{'New','Working'}; directly in code and modify query to use statuses22  instead of statuses.  And result was proper. Could it problem of square bracket? becoz when i printed these values using debug statement statuses22  was = (New, Working)    and   statuses  was  = [New, Working]

Comment: Totally depends on code how its implemented if ApplicationStatus is a list of string, I guess you need to split it and directly use in the method, if its semicolon seperated string, you need to split it.

Comment: Application_1_Lead_Status__c  is single select picklist on Lead but Application status is not a field on lead but just a multiselect picklist on vf page.  So when user selects applications on vf page  it will be {New;Working}  and after spiting and putting them in list of string its [New,Working]. Now when we are using this list in SOQL its not working.

Comment: Can you please go through my last comment ? I am talking about data types here, List vs String. The SOQL works fines. So it has to be something in the code. Without looking at the code cant really blame SOQL